# htaccess: Redirect to https not working with out www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I just installed the Origin CA certificate in CentOS 7.3 with the help of this [link](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217472077-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-certificate-in-Apache-httpd) 
Then I redirected all the `http` requests to `https` and `www` to `non-www` with the following `.htaccess` commands

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

here are the following issues,

1) When I set `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` it gives `Too Many Redirects` error

2) When I access the site with follwing URL http://website.com, It doesn't redirect to https

3) but, http://www.website.com works fine (with WWW)

Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong in the SSL configuration, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `http://www.website.com` redirects to `https://website.com` (WORKS FINE). But `http://website.com` doesn't redirect

Comment: Apache 2.4.6 ...

Comment: again it says `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Comment: probably you are right, this time `http://www.website.com` redirects to `https://website.com` (WORKS FINE). But `http://website.com` doesn't work with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http` OR `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace both `http->https` and `www->non-www` redirect rules with this single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www and turn on https rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: this time `http://www.website.com` redirects to `https://website.com` (WORKS FINE). But `http://website.com` doesn't work

Comment: Not sure, it works for me on a live site. `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off` or `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http` or `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https`should work.